# Convex hull of points in $\mathbb{S}^n$ not contained in a hemisphere

Tags: riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Suppose I have $n+2$ points in $\mathbb{S}^n$ in the induced metric. In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76875/convex-hull-on-a-riemannian-manifold), the asker states that the convex hull of any four points in $\mathbb{S}^2$ which are not contained in a hemisphere must be all of $\mathbb{S}^2$ (they give a citation, but I don't have access to it). I have tried to prove it myself, but I haven't made much progress. How is this result proved? Also, I suspect that that a similar result holds in higher dimensions. Is this the case?

Comment: Don't you mean the convex cone, not the convex hull?

Comment: I mean the convex hull, as in the smallest convex set containing all the points. I'd be happy with any suitable definition of *convex*, such as "$X$ is convex if every pair of distinct points $p,q \in X$ are joined by a minimising geodesic in $\mathbb{S}^n$ which is contained in $X$".

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: the result continues to hold in higher dimensions. Several authors (Danzer, Grünbaum and Klee, [Helly's theorem and its relatives](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eandyp/teaching/2013SpringMath366/DanzerGruenbaumKlee.pdf), citing e.g. Robinson, [Spherical theorems of Helly type and congruence indices of spherical caps](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2371682.pdf) and Blumenthal, [Metric methods in linear inequalities](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.dmj/1077475197)) assert without proof that convex sets (in the sense that every pair of non-antipodal points are connected by a minimising geodesic, the first reference also uses some other definitions) are intersections of hemispheres.